# asp.net webform Repeater, Update a set of textbox, Add to the List / Array

Tags: asp.net, webforms, repeater

I am working on old webform asp.net application which uses Repeater.

The Repeater is a set of Name and address textbox fields. I have 3 sets of Name and Address information, basically, 3 sets of records in the object list to bind.

On the UI, I changed/update one of the Name and Address. I noticed in the list, which it iterate or loops through the repeater control

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in this.NameAddressRepeaterControl.Items)
```

I see that an extra recod is added to the items.

Question:

I am used to fixed textboxes. When I update the textbox, I write code to take *Exactly* what is filled in the textbox and populate the DTO object to pass to the data layer to perform database transaction to update the database records. 
When the new updated record is added to the Repeater Control list, I don't know which records is updated and which is the new records.

I am checking out OnItemDataBound and OnItemCommand to see if there is a way to get the old value from one of the field and also record the value of the new value. Is this possible?

The form contains 1 Save button and it will loop through the Repeater.Items to see what Name/Address to extract, but the new and old company exist in this list.

Instead of looping through the RepeaterControl.Items, Is there a way to extract from directly the visible Repeater control? If there are 3 repeater Name/Address control, is there a way to get all the info from each of the 3 sets of Repeater controls? The Repeater wraps around a user control, NameAddressCtrl.

I prefer not to replace the Repeater controls with fixed textboxes.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: a little more code wouldn´t hurt ;) du you have in each repeater item a button to save changes ? or one for all ?

Comment: Its One for All.

Comment: Did you wrap the databinding of the Repeater inside `if (!Page.IsPostBack) { //bind here }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed the code several time and add additional code to keep track what was add and changed in the repeated and only passed the information to be saved to the db. The solution was to write additional code. I did not change anything with the repeater behavior. Thanks for the comments and help.